# Using NgFor in an NgIf and NgIfElse block

Tags: angular

I would like to switch between two different databases in my html. I've set up a `boolean` `isNow` which is equal to `true` on start but when a `date` is clicked in the calendar, triggering the `onChange($event)`, it would then set the `isNow` `boolean` to `false`. If `isNow` is equal to `true` then `ngFor` would `let getObj of databaseA'` but I would like the `ngFor` to cycle through my `databaseB` `*ngFor="let getObj of databaseB"` instead. In addition, when a `button` is clicked, it switches the `isNow` value back to `true` I tried this so far but for some reason it isn't working. Here is the code I've tried so far

```
  databaseA: Observable<any[]>; 
  databaseB: Observable<any[]>;
  isNow: boolean = true;


  get data(): string {
    return this.databaseService.serviceData;
  }

  set data(date) { 
    this.databaseService.serviceData= (moment(date).format(dateFormat)); 
  }   


  @Input() placeholder;
  @Output() onFilter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() selectedValue;
  @Output() selectedValueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  private _selectedValue;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase, public databaseService: DatabaseService){
    this.databaseA = db.list('databaseA').valueChanges();
    this.databaseB = db.list('databaseB/'+this.databaseService.serviceData).valueChanges();   
  }

  toggleNow(){
  this.isNow = true; 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._selectedValue = this.data;    
  }

  onChange($event) {
    this.selectedValue = this.updateDate($event.value);
    this.onFilter.emit(this.data);
    this.isNow = false;
  }

  updateDate(date) {
    let formatedDate;
    if (date !== undefined) {
      formatedDate = moment(date).format(dateFormat);      
    }    
    this.selectedValueChange.emit(formatedDate);  
    return formatedDate;   
  }
}
```

In the HTML component I used this:

```
<button mat-button (click)=“toggleNow()"> NOW </button>
<ng-container *ngIf=isNow>
    <option ngFor=“let getObj of databaseA|async”></option>
    <option ngIfElse=“let getObj of databaseB|async></option>
    <div>{{getObj.name}}</div>
    <div>{{getObj.field}}</div>
    <div>{{getObj.status}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

The reason for this is when a date is switched then a database showing a certain set of values will be shown but if the viewer wants to see current info then the now button will give this option. I'm using Angular 7. I feel like this should be possible. I believe this is the logic that should be used and I've tried different ways to set this up but alas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngIfElse cannot be used with ngFor syntax. Rather you can consider the below solution. It will work same.

```
<ng-container *ngIf=isNow>
  <option *ngFor=“let getObj of databaseA|async”></option>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf=!isNow>
  <option *ngFor=“let getObj of databaseB|async"></option>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to put `*ngFor` instead of `ngFor`. As an additional side note, i decided to use this with a table. As a result, I put a `div` before the `tbody` and that contained the `*ngIf` statement. In `tbody` I placed the `*ngFor` directive. Also, I had to add a `style="all:inherit"` to maintain my `tbody` styling.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed the *. Just updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your if else condition to achieve this, you can do like this.

```
<ng-template #selectedData>
    <option *ngFor=“let getObj of databaseA|async”></option>
    <div>{{getObj.name}}</div>
    <div>{{getObj.field}}</div>
    <div>{{getObj.status}}</div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #CurrentData>
    <option *ngFor=“let getObj of databaseB|async></option>
    <div>{{getObj.name}}</div>
    <div>{{getObj.field}}</div>
    <div>{{getObj.status}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I tried this method as well but I couldn't get it to work for me so I used @Manzurul approached.